# How is this equation equivalent for an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: ode]

Could someone explain how the left-hand side is equivalent to the right-hand side of the section I circled in red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that:
\begin{align*}
\ln |N| - \ln |K - N| &= rt + C \\
\ln \left| \frac{N}{K - N} \right| &= rt + C \\
\left| \frac{N}{K - N} \right| &= e^{rt + C} \\
\left| \frac{N}{K - N} \right| &= e^C e^{rt} \\
\frac{N}{K - N} &= \pm e^C e^{rt} \\
\frac{N}{K - N} &= A e^{rt} \\
N &= K A e^{rt} - N A e ^ {rt} \\
N + N A e ^ {rt} &= K A e^{rt} \\
N(1 + A e ^ {rt}) &= K A e^{rt} \\
N &= \frac{K A e^{rt}}{1 + A e ^ {rt}} \\
\end{align*}